# C# - Assign value to object's property by assigning them directly to the instance

Tags: c#, properties, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Considering the following class:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
    public bool IsMaried { get; set; }
        
    public override string ToString()
        => $"{Name} was born on {Birth.ToShortDateString()} and is{(IsMaried ? "" : " not")} maried";
}
```

How could I write code like this:

```
var person = new Person();
person += "Erick"; // string should be assigned to the Name property of the instance.
person += new DateTime(1998, 10, 28); // DateTime object should be assigned to Birth property of the instance.
person += true; // bool should be assigned to IsMaried property of the instance.
```

At first, [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) seemed to be the gotcha, but I've had no success with that.

I know that there's an workaround like:

```
public void Set<T>(PersonField field, T value);
```

But I'd like to know if it can be achieved in the former fashion.

Comment: What behavior do you expect if class `Person` will have 2 props with same type?

Comment: This is stringent upon the fact that each variable of the class be unique type

Comment: You *could* do this with operator overloading (defining `public static Person operator+(Person person, object value)`) but I'd *strongly* advise against it. The code is extremely hard to understand, compared with just assigning properties directly.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it is possible. I'm not going to write an actual answer because I think this is a crackpot idea and the answer could cause other programmers more harm than good. You should reconsider your design.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but maybe you can find this object initialization useful:


Person person = new Person() {
Name = "Erick",
Birth = DateTime.Parse("10-28-1998"),
IsMaried = true };

Comment: @ErickRuhCardozo Don't overload addition `+=` operator  to do assignments, please. It is very very anti-pattern and misleading thing. A VERY VERY BIG design fault. Run away from this kind of idea like the plague and have a good job.

Comment: come on guys, this is more than obviously an academic question. It's so stupidly simple to do it right, but Erick wanted to know how to hack it. Obviously there are some guys who even did not know it's possible (see below). There are more than enough warning, but I cannot see a reason to close it. it perfectly meets all SO standards.

Comment: not a single comment or answer is encouraging or misleading, everyone is aware it's only for the sake of it. where is the problem? Don't be so german and strict, be more laissez-faire :)

Answer (score 3):

it's ugly, but it does what you asked for;

```
void Main()
{
    var person = new Person();
    person += "Erick"; // string should be assigned to the Name property of the instance.
    person += new DateTime(1998, 10, 28); // DateTime object should be assigned to Birth property of the instance.
    person += true; // bool should be assigned to IsMaried property of the instance.
    Console.WriteLine(person);
    //Output
    //Erick was born on 28.10.1998 and is maried
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
    public bool IsMaried { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
        => $"{Name} was born on {Birth.ToShortDateString()} and is{(IsMaried ? "" : " not")} maried";

    public static Person operator +(Person p, string n)
    {   
        p.Name=n;
        return p;
    }
    public static Person operator +(Person p, DateTime b)
    {
        p.Birth=b;
        return p;
    }
    public static Person operator +(Person p, bool b)
    {
        p.IsMaried = b;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: And then we get into the real question:  Why is this desirable?  If it's an academic hacking exercise, then fine.

Comment: true, but all these true comments are already below the question... ;)

Comment: Gawd that's hideous. And has the problem of what if you have more than one variable as a property. i.e. two strings FirstName LastName.

Comment: You should be ashamed of having proposed such a solution :)

Comment: :) I am young and need points...

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "Erick";
person.Birth = DateTime.Parse("10-28-1998");
person.IsMarried = true;
Debug.WriteLine("Person ToString: " + person.ToString());
```

Comment: that's not an answer to the question!

Comment: Person is an object class. You can't assign data to the class by doing += that only works for variables like int, string ect. You must assign data using the Objects properties.

Comment: this is not true!  the question even contains the way how to do (overload operator). Check Events or delegates they have built-in `+` and `-`operators and of course used with classes / ref types.

Comment: You're going to get "Operator  '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Person' and 'bool'" for instance when doing "person += true;" C# has no idea which property you are referring to. Why are you trying to do this anyhow?

Comment: please see my answer for "how", but not "why"